# GAE app.yaml - get script and parameter from custom short URL?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, app.yaml

My main question is, is this even possible.

My current live application is `mylongnamedapp.com`

I also own `shortna.me` (for example).

I want to implement a short url link function to save characters in SMS messages so I want to be able to have users click a link like this `http://shortna.me/a/f423f`

Now, `shortna.me` would resolve to `mylongnamedapp.com` so could I do any of the following:

1. Have a script called `a.php` and have app.yaml 'decode' `http://shortna.me/a/f423f` to script `a.php` with a parameter of `f423f`?
2. Have a folder called `a`and have app.yaml run a default script within and run it with the parameter `f423f`?

Is either of the above possible with app.yaml on Google App Engine?

Comment: Note that the `app.yaml` file doesn't make routing decisions based on the domain name, it only uses the filepath, so in your example the routing decision will only be based on `/a/f423f`. So both `http://shortna.me/a/f423f` and `http://mylongnamedapp.com/a/f423f` will produce the same result unless you specifically parse the URL domain inside your script and react differently. It might not be an issue at all, up to you to decide. That is if you also map `shortna.me` to your app (to avoid a redirect), of course.

Comment: Yes that's cool. The reason for the question is the shortness because if length wasn't an issue I would go with `http://mylongnamedapp.com/thescript.php?id=f423f` so if I can do `http://mylongnamedapp.com/a/f423f` with app.yaml, I can sort out the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question properly, you want your App Engine application to route requests to `/a/some_value` to the script `a.php` with the parameter `some_value`.

Here you have a small working example which you will be able to adapt to your case scenario:

***app.yaml***

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /a/.*
  script: a.php
```

***a.php***

```
<html>
  <body>
    <?php
    $str = $_SERVER[PATH_INFO];
    $str2 = explode("/",$str)[2]; 

    echo "This function is using the parameter: " . $str2;
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then you can execute this code with the command:

```
dev_appserver.py app.yaml --php_executable_path <PATH_TO_PHP-CGI>
```

You will see that the application is executing the `a.php` script according to the handlers in `app.yaml`, and mapping the end of the query to a paremeter with which to work.

Answer (score 0):

With the answer from @dsesto I have taken this one step further and removed the need for the script to be in the `/a` directory. So rather than `http://shortna.me/a/f423f`, I can use `http://shortna.me/f423f`.

My new direction will see me use a 6 character alphanumeric code. Because app.yaml uses regex, this is what I've done:

```
- url: /[a-zA-Z\d]{6}
  script: a.php
  secure: always
```

So anything that matches the regex `[a-zA-Z\d]{6}` will be sent to `a.php`. But I do actually have a handler for `mylongnamedapp.com/signup` ('signup' being 6 characters) - as long as that handler is above this regex, it works. So the full result looks like this:

```
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1
  secure: always

- url: /signup
  script: signup.php
  secure: always

- url: /[a-zA-Z\d]{6}
  script: test.php
  secure: always

- url: /.*
  script: home.php
  secure: always
```

The first handler looks after specic pages like `login.php`.

The second one is specific for signup because the URL is pretty and doesn't use `.php` in the marketing material.

The third is the answer to this question.

And the last one is a catch-all to send non-matching requests to the default home page.